# Disable blue glow tab indicator for notification in Firefox Quantum

Tags: notifications, firefox

I want to disable the blue glow indicator in Firefox Quantum tabs (v. 58.0.2 (64-bit)).

The indicator appears below the favicon of the tabs with new content/notifications (see image under Twitter favicon).

[image]

How can I disable this feature? I tried putting on `userChrome.css` the following style sheet but it doesn't work.

```
.tabbrowser-tab[pinned][titlechanged]:not([selected="true"]) {
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(hsla(0,0%,100%,.2), hsla(0,0%,45%,.2) 2px, hsla(0,0%,32%,.2) 80%) !important;
}
 .tabbrowser-tab[pinned][titlechanged]:not([selected="true"]):hover {
   background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(hsla(0,0%,100%,.6), hsla(0,0%,100%,.2) 4px, hsla(0,0%,75%,.2) 80%) !important;
}
```

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/85761/46291